# add element to a linked list(C)

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I want to make a link list that i can add more element to later but the problem i have with the current code is that the all previous elements are overwritten by the last element added.here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node {
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
}*head;



void add( char *str ) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->name=str;

    if (head== NULL) {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;

    } else {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void  display(struct node *r) {
    r=head;
    if(r==NULL)
        return;

    while(r!=NULL) {
        printf("%s ",r->name);
        r=r->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int  main()
{
    char *str;
    struct node *n;
    head=NULL;
    while(scanf("%s",str) == 1) {
        add(str);
        display(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not have a better attempt at indenting the code? Perhaps learning to use the debugger is the order of the day

Comment: function `display` do not need `r` as argument. Try `void display(){struct node * r=head;...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
int  main()
{
  char *str;
```

to

```
int  main()
{
  char str[100];  // Or some other value to give scanf somewhere to put the data
```

Then in add (assuming that this function is available on your set up)

```
temp->name=strdup(str);
```

I leave freeing the memory as an exercise for the reader

Comment: Ps: Is `strdup` is not available do `malloc(strlen(str) + 1); strcpy(temp-name, str);`

Comment: Additionally, `display(n);` should be `display(head);`

Comment: @AntoJurković - Correct - I did not get that far :-(

Comment: @Anto Jurković. i removed the r parameter and it doesn't work any more.why?

Answer (score 3):

In your `add` you use construction

```
temp->name=str;
```

It doesn't perform string copy, it just make `temp->name` point to `str`. You should use `strcpy` instead. Something like

```
temp->name = (char*) malloc(strlen(str)+1);
strcpy(temp->name, str);
```

And in your main function you should allocate memory for variable `str`, before using it in `scanf`.

```
char* str = (char *)malloc(255);
...
free(str);
```

or

```
char str[255];
```

Comment: It is tagged C - so new is out - try malloc. (also need to add one for the null character)

Comment: @Ed Heal You are totally right, I will correct answer.

Comment: You do not need the cast on malloc either

Comment: @Ed Heal I know. This is to emphasize that the function `malloc` return `void * `.